# Password Validation in Asp.Net Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

The password format for my application is implemented in IdentityConfig.cs, as below:

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 6,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
    RequireDigit = true,
    RequireLowercase = true,
    RequireUppercase = true,
};
```

However, the validation message is "Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character" which is not that clear to most users.

I wanted to change it, so I added a custom validation as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PasswordAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return "The password should be a combination of upper case, lower case letters, digits and special characters";
    }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;

        if (value.ToString().Length == 8)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I have also referred to this validation in the Model as follows:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
[CustomValidations.Password]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

However, the password validation message is still the same as before. What am I missing? How to change the default validation message for the password field?

Is there a way to modify the validation message inside IdentityConfig.cs?

Comment: Try `using CustomValidations` and only `[Password]` for the validation attribute.  Also, in your logic, you are only validating the length of the string so maybe you are meeting the requirements.

Comment: My bad, I did not include the complete validation inside the model. Added it now.

Comment: Rename your `PasswordAttribute` to `CustomPasswordAttribute` and then use it as `[CustomPassword]` instead of `[CustomValidations.Password]`. It should work

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tanvir, but this didn't help. Basically I just renamed the PasswordAttribute class. 

However, I realised that implementing a regular expression validator will help more. So I am working on that, trying to figure out a suitable reg. expression for my password requirements.

Comment: I figured out the problem. My isValid() function inside customer validator was not implemented correctly.